# Change ToggleButton style in code behind when IsChecked changes in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, togglebutton

Here is my `ToggleButton`:

```
<ToggleButton ToolTip="Walk!"  Name="NavigateWalkOrbitToggleButton" Width="35" Height="35"  Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleToggleButtonStyle}" Checked="NavigateWalkOrbitToggleButton_Checked">
     <iconPacks:PackIconMaterial Kind="Walk" />
</ToggleButton>
```

and in code behind:

```
private void NavigateWalkOrbitToggleButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RemoveCheckedToggleButtons();
    NavisDocumentControl.Document.Tool.Value = Autodesk.Navisworks.Api.Tool.NavigateFreeOrbit;
}
```

When I click it, the style is changing correctly but when I change `IsChecked` to `false` or `true` from code behind, the style does not change.

I'm using         `xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls`

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with your `Style`? Could you post the `MetroCircleToggleButtonStyle` as well?

Comment: is the code behind change required because  you should be using data triggers in the style to make changes, not code behind see: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/styles/trigger-datatrigger-event-trigger/

Comment: also you haven't provided any code behind so how can we say what is wrong?

Comment: @MikeT `NavigateWalkOrbitToggleButton.IsChecked = false;`

Comment: Your issue is not reproducible. What are you doing in your NavigateWalkOrbitToggleButton_Checked event handler?

Comment: i have added code behind

Comment: in `RemoveCheckedToggleButtons();` simply `X_buttons,IsChecked = false;`

Comment: Your issue is still not reproducible: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Where you set the NavigateWalkOrbitToggleButton.IsChecked property?

Comment: your wpf is `NavigateWalkOrbitToggleButton_Checked` your code behind is `NavigateWalkOrbitToggleButton` either you have made a typo or you've misnamed the handler

Answer (score 0):

You are taking a very bad practive approach to this,

A DataTrigger would be a much better approach

this would look something like this

```
<ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}"  BasedOn="{DynamicResource MetroCircleToggleButtonStyle}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"></Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ToggleButton.Style>
    test
</ToggleButton>
```

Given what you have show code wise its rather hard to say exactly why your code is not working as your code wont even compile this is because

```
Checked="NavigateWalkOrbitToggleButton_Checked"
```

and your code behind says

```
private void NavigateWalkOrbitToggleButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

so the event handler doesn't exist

in addition you don't show the code your question states you are running that changes the IsChecked property

one option could be you are only handling Checked which will only occurs when Ischecked is clicked to become true and not Unchecked

so as the first thing your checked handler does is RemoveCheckedToggleButtons() the check is being unset as soon as its set